# Why cant i access websites via proxied Cloudflare?

Tags: dns, ip, vpn, cloudflare, vps

I Live in Estonia.
The second day I observe some kind of problem with the opening of some of my sites.
Example:
https://cp.nasdaq.ee - sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't
https://185.252.232.227:8888/ - this is the same site cp.nasdaq.ee, but via IP - always opens properly

If the site is down and i enable the VPN, then it starts working.
In all other countries, the site opens without problems https://www.host-tracker.com/ru/ic/4/697585f4-486b-4c8e-b530-e3f0b6c96972/
This problem have all of my friends (5 men) who live in Estonia.

Perhaps the problem is somehow related to the fact that cp.nasdaq.ee has NS servers in the Cloudflare.com zone, but not all sites connected to Cloudflare have the problem.
I observe the problem only for those sites that are connected to Cloudflare and their A-record leads to ip 185.252.232.227.
If IP 109.205.176.239, 62.171.151.28, 62.171.151.28 are specified, then sites open without problems.

For your information,
all IPs listed are for VPS owned by Contabo.com hosting, the server is located in Germany.
The problematic IP 185.252.232.227 is from one VPS on Contabo, and all the other IPs I listed are from another VPS on Contabo.

And if i turn of status Proxied at CLoduflare.com and set DNS ONLY - then website works well!

Here is such an incomprehensible problem ...

[image]

[image]